# SQL Sum window function

Tags: sql, window-functions

I have a table where I need one more column with sum values for 4 previous rows.

The table is something like this:
[image]

So for example in that new column for row number 5, value should be 29 because 4 rows before that have 6+8+8+7 = 29.

I know I should probably use window function, which I tried but without success to make it sum 4 previous values from order_rate column. (with partition by, with order by, with between, etc..) I'm probably missing something small as usual :'(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which database are you using but this solution should work on most of them. You can set the *window frame* to indicate the specific subrange of rows you want to aggregate. For example:

```
select t.*,
  sum(order_rate) over(
    order by quarter_time
    rows between 4 preceding and 1 preceding -- window frame
  ) as new_sum
from t
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you want by using something like

SUM(order_rate) OVER (ORDER BY quarter_time ROWS 4 PRECEDING) - order_rate

The window function will sum up the preceding 4 rows order_rates as well as the current row so subtracting the current rows order_rate value at the end gets the sum of the previous 4 values only.